# Android: Difference between onDraw() and surfaceCreated() within a SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, surfaceview, ondraw

I have looked at several references. In most cases, the `onDraw()` method is included along with the required `surfaceCreated()` method in a SurfaceView. According to another post, `onDraw()` is the method that's called when the SurfaceView is drawn, and `surfaceCreated()` is the method that is called when the SurfaceView is created. What is the difference? What would go in each? Where would you start a separate thread to be used for the SurfaceView?

Comment: See also https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onDraw()` is called on every `invalidate()` of the SurfaceView. `surfaceCreated()` is only called when the surface is initially created.
The `onDraw()` method should contain all of your drawing code to produce the desired graphics. In the `surfaceCreated()` method you might query initial parameters like the surface's width and height.